# Is Intel AESNI supported by Xen in VPS/Cloud hosting environments?

Tags: xen, encryption

I'm having trouble determining whether when using a hosting company that uses Xen virtualization and Intel processors with AESNI embedded encryption, I would have access to AESNI (i.e., is it an available hardware resource in such environments).

Answer (score 2):

At the command line type:

cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep aes

If it's there, it's supported; if it's not, it's not.

To answer your question though, Xen 4.0.1+ support AES-NI instructions in guests.

Comment: Do you have any reference for that?